# how to write a simple code that sends email

Tags: c#, asp.net

i developed a simple website that stores in the user name and  sends that to my emailid and then downloads a file.File is getting downloaded but not mailing me the username.

```
             try
            {
                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                mailMessage.To.Add("mygmailid");
               mailMessage.From =new MailAddress("mydomainbasedemailid");
                mailMessage.Subject = "ASP.NET e-mail test";
   mailMessage.Body = "Hello world,\n\nThis is an ASP.NET test e-mail!";
         SmtpClient smtpClient=new SmtpClient("mail.mydomain.com",587);
                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
                Response.Write("E-mail sent!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
   Response.Write("Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Is there an exception thrown?

Comment: What happens when you debug, does an Exception occure, or does the code run fine but you dont receive the mail?

Comment: Code run fine without an exception but not receive the email

Comment: You could try to debug the mail sending with something like [Papercut](https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut). Once you are sure that you send out the right thing, switch back to your actual mail server address and handle any remaining problem on mailserver-side

Comment: Did you also check spam folders? Make at least sure that the "From" address is the owner of the mailbox you use to send.

Comment: Now its giving an excption -Could not send the e-mail - error: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Smtp.Credentials like this:

```
string HOSTLOGIN = "YourHostLogin";
string HOSTPW = "YourTopSecretPasswort";

var credentials = 
       new System.Net.NetworkCredential() { UserName = HOSTLOGIN, Password = HOSTPW };
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
client.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: Added ur part.but still not receiving the email

Comment: @nashco Sry i forgot the part: `smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;` I have updated my answer. Also try to set: `client.EnableSsl = true;`

Comment: Now its giving an excption -Could not send the e-mail - error: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Comment: Did you set the credentials right? And please make sure you take the right order: you have to set `smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;` before you set the credentials: `smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;`